# A question about ; in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

```
exit()
```

is valid,but

```
exit()
echo 1;
```

Will fail.

Why?

Comment: Isn't it simply that the semicolon is optional on the last statement of the block or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The semicolon terminates a statement, although it's not required if it's the last statement.

Comment: … last statement in the PHP block.

Comment: The semicolon doesn't terminate a statement. It **separates** two of them. That's why you can omit the semicolon at the end of a script/block.

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct syntax , the later isn't. If more than one command is provided, they have to be separated via `;`. `echo 1` wouldn't be executed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
exit()
```

will work only if it is at the end

But

```
exit()
echo 1;
```

In this case it is not on the end.

Comment: @Felix `exit` is always the last statement that runs but not usually the last statement in the file. It's kinda pointless exiting or dieing as the script is about to end normally

Comment: one extra word (file) made the mess out of it, sorry, corrected it, thanks all